# The method getText() is undefined for the type String error

Tags: android

```
 String email = email.getText().toString();
```

Please help getting error The method getText() is undefined for the type String

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change - `String email = email.getText().toString()` to

```
String emailStr = email.getText().toString()
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have shadowed an attribute `email` by calling a variable with the same name.

Hence `email` does not reference what you meant anymore (a textfield I suppose) but a String.

You should change the name of your variable.

Comment: can you suggest solution i am new to android.you mean i should change the reference variable

Comment: I propose to do what Vishal adviced : rename your variable to `emailStr` : `String emailStr = email.getText().toString()`

Comment: ok i got it thanks guys really appreciate your immediate response

Answer (score 1):

Assume the id of your EditText is **email**. To get the Text of the EditText you can use

```
String email = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
```